# Finding the maximum number of subspaces of a vector space over finite field that satisfy these relations

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, vector-spaces, finite-groups, finite-fields

I have a question and I am stuck. I was wondering if anyone has a thought, before I start a brute-force search.

> For $q$ a prime number and $n =6$, let $\mathbb {F}_{q}^{n}$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{q}$.
>   Furthermore, let $ U_1, \dots, U_m$ be a family of $2$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_{q}^n$ such that $U_i \cap U_j = \{0\}$ and $\langle U_i, U_j \rangle \cap U_k = \{0\}$, for all $i, j, k \in \{1,\dots, n\}$, $i\neq j \neq k$. What is the biggest possible $m$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting question. Equivalently stated, you are looking for the maximum number of $2$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb F_q^6$ such that each three of them span the whole space.

Comment: Correct.But in addition they have to be pairwise disjoint.

Comment: The disjointness condition (by the way, you mean "trivial intersection", I guess) is redundant for $m\geq 3$: If $U_1 \cap U_2 \neq \{0\}$, then $\dim(U_1 + U_2) \leq 3$, so $U_1 + U_2 + U_3$ can never be of dimension $6$.

Comment: Each $1$-dimensional subspace is contained in at most one $U_i$. This gives the upper bound $m \leq q^3 + 1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks for your comment. You are right, $(q^6 - 1)/(q^2 - 1) = q^4 + q^2 + 1$ is the upper bound we get in this way. I did the wrong division $(q^6 - 1)/(q^3 - 1)$. What a shame that I cannot edit the other comment any more.

Comment: Don't worry about the old comment. The idea is fine. But I don't think it is sharp, because once we have picked two 2-d subspaces, their direct sum contains other 1-d subspaces (quite a few them actually), and these will then be off limits. But then it gets messy.

Comment: I also don't think that $m\leq q^4+q^2+1$ is sharp. Because it may contain subsets which do not fulfill the requirement for $\langle U_i, U_j \rangle \cap U_k = \{0\}$, for all $i, j, k \in \{1,\dots, n\}$, $i\neq j \neq k$

Comment: There is an easy construction of $q^2+1$ subspaces: The 1-d spaces $U_\alpha$ over $K=\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ generated by a vector of the form $(1,\alpha,\alpha^2)$ with $\alpha\in K$, together with $U_\infty$ generated by $(0,0,1)$. Doesn't feel optimal. Viewing $\mathbb{F}_q^6$ as $K^3$ here obviously.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Yeah, I just had the same idea :) For $q$ even you can improve the lower bound to $q^2 + 2$, by taking a hyperoval.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Nice observation about the non-sharpness of the upper bound! It suggests that the right number of $m$ should be considerably smaller than $q^4 + q^2 + 1$.

Comment: Yeah, but those 4-d spaces $U_i+U_j$ may intersect non-trivially (in a space of dimension at most two), so the 1-d subspaces contained in them can be reused. At least I cannot rule out the possibility. Some averaging argument may be out there...

Comment: @azimut Your lower bound of $q^2+2$ is in fact sharp; see my answer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Your construction is at least very close to optimal; an upper bound is give by $q^2+2$, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $q$ be a prime power and let $\mathcal{U}$ be a collection of $2$-dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb{F}_q^6$ such that for any three distinct planes $U_1,U_2,U_3\in\mathcal{U}$ we have
$$U_1\cap U_2=0\qquad\text{ and }\qquad (U_1+U_2)\cap U_3=0.$$
Then $\dim(U_1+U_2)=4$ and $\dim(U_1+U_2+U_3)=6$. Pick $U_0\in\mathcal{U}$ and let $\mathcal{U}':=\mathcal{U}-\{U_0\}$. Then for every $U\in\mathcal{U}'$ the quotient $(U_0+U_1)/U_0$ is a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb{F}_q^6/U_0$.

**Lemma:** For $U_1,U_2\in\mathcal{U}'$ with $U_1\neq U_2$ we have
$$(U_0+U_1)/U_0\ \cap\ (U_0+U_2)/U_0=0.$$

*Proof.* It suffices to note that $(U_0+U_1)\cap(U_0+U_2)=U_0$, which follows from the fact that 
$$\dim((U_0+U_1)+(U_0+U_2))=\dim(U_0+U_1+U_2)=6.$$

**Corollary:** The set
$$X:=\Big\{(U_0+U)/U_0-\{0\}:\ U\in\mathcal{U}'\Big\},$$
is a collection of disjoint subsets of $\Bbb{F}_q^6/U_0-\{0\}$ with $|X|=|\mathcal{U}'|$.

As noted $\dim((U_0+U)/U_0)=2$ and clearly $\dim(\Bbb{F}_q^6/U_0)=4$ so it follows that
$$(q^2-1)|X|\leq q^4-1,$$
or equivalently $|\mathcal{U}'|\leq q^2+1$ and hence $|\mathcal{U}|\leq q^2+2$.

---

The comments by JyrkiLahtonen and azimut indicate constructions of collections $\mathcal{U}$ with $|\mathcal{U}|=q^2+1$ for odd $q$, and $|\mathcal{U}|=q^2+2$ for even $q$. So this leaves only the question:

> Is there such a collection $\mathcal{U}$ with $|\mathcal{U}|=q^2+2$ when $q$ is odd?

If, for example, projective $3$-space over $\Bbb{F}_q$ can be partitioned into projective lines, then the answer is *yes*.

---

**Old answer:**

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a set of planes in $\Bbb{F}_q^6$ such that for any three planes $U_1,U_2,U_3\in\mathcal{U}$ we have
$$U_i\cap U_j=\{0\}\qquad\text{ and }\qquad\langle U_i,U_j\rangle\cap U_k=\{0\}.$$
Then $\langle U_i,U_j,U_k\rangle=\Bbb{F}_q^6$, so no three planes in $\mathcal{U}$ are contained in a single $5$-dimensional subspace. Every pair $U_i,U_j\in\mathcal{U}$ spans a $4$-dimensional subspace, and there are $q+1$ different $5$-dimensional subspaces containing it. Then no other plane in $\mathcal{U}$ is contained in any of these $q+1$ subspaces. This holds for any pair of planes in $\mathcal{U}$. The total number of $5$-dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb{F}_q^6$ is
$$\frac{q^6-1}{q-1}=q^5+q^4+q^3+q^2+q+1,$$
so the number of pairs of planes in $\mathcal{U}$ is at most
$$\frac{q^5+q^4+q^3+q^2+q+1}{q+1}=q^4+q^2+1.$$
Let $m:=|\mathcal{U}|$ be the number of planes in $\mathcal{U}$. Then the above says that
$$\binom{m}{2}\leq q^4+q^2+1,$$
where $\tbinom{m}{2}=\tfrac{1}{2}m(m-1)$. The quadratic formula then tells us that
$$m\leq\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1+8(q^4+q^2+1)}=\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2q^4+2q^2+\tfrac{9}{4}}.$$
This gives us an upper bound for the biggest possible $m$, which is close to the lower bound of $q^2+1\leq m$ given in the comments in the sense that
$$\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2q^4+2q^2+\tfrac{9}{4}}\leq\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2}(q^2+1).$$

Comment: nice insight to this old question. Your remaining question has a positive answer: The projective 3-space over GF(q) can always be partitioned into projective lines. Such a set of lines is called a spread. The standard construction is to take all $q^2+1$ 1-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$-subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}^2$ and then consider it as a set of 2-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_q$-subspaces.